# Can I re-fight Cardia?

Tags: shovel-knight, shovel-knight-king-of-cards

After beating every Joustus champion, I talked to Cardia and was transported to a different dimension. After defeating her in Joustus and fighting her as a boss, she disappeared from my ship.

Is there any way to re-fight Cardia once I’ve completed her fight?